# Посоветуйте средства валидации xml по xsd java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Если мы воспользуемся библиотекой SAXParserFactory, то во время цикла на первой ошибки - цикл обрывается, при этом мы получаем только одну ошибку.
А мне требуется показать все ошибки сразу.

Уточните, пожалуйста, имеется ли что-то подходящее для моей задачи?

P.S. фатальные ошибки (не закрыли на конце тег и т.д.) - не берем в счет. 
P.S.S имеется введу что SAXParserFactory проверяет в теге тип данных по xsd и если он не соответствует, то запинается и дальше проверка не идет.

Спасибо!

Comment: Допустим, в xsd идут поочерёдно узлы типа int и string. А в xml узлы идут наоборот: сперва string, потом int. Сколько ошибок должен выдать валидатор: всего одну (узлы сдвинуты на одну позицию) или много (по одной на каждый узел)? Имхо, задача сложнорешаемая. Это как диффы в тексте. Может угадать, может нет.

Comment: Спасибо. Но помог данный пост http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131662/how-to-validate-xml-against-xsd-and-get-all-errorsи задача решена

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.